# left join по условию

Tags: postgresql

Переведу свою задачу на классический пример. Допустим есть таблица покупателей и покупок. Понятно, что у каждого покупателя может быть от 0 до N покупок:

```
    customer              order
   ╔════╦════════╗       ╔════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
   ║ id ║ name   ║       ║ id ║ customer_id ║date        ║
   ╠════╬════════╣       ╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
   ║ 1  ║  One   ║       ║ 1  ║  1          ║ 2018-10-10 ║       
   ║ 2  ║  Two   ║       ║ 2  ║  1          ║ 2018-10-15 ║
   ║ 3  ║  Three ║       ║ 3  ║  2          ║ 2018-10-30 ║
   ╚════╩════════╝       ╚════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Мне нужно заджойнить покупки к покупателям

```
select * 
  from customer c 
  left join order o 
  on c.id = o.custoner_id;
```

таким образом, чтоб в ряду с покупателем была либо последняя покупка, либо не было покупок вовсе.

В результате каждый покупатель должен появиться в итоговой таблице только один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT o.customer_id, MAX(o.`date`) `date`
            FROM order o 
            GROUP BY o.customer_id ) l
on c.id = l.customer_id;
```